# How to copy some data from one table to another?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have two tables `Products` and `NotArrivedOrders` (all columns are `nvarchar(50)`).

Now in products I have this columns :

1. ProductName.
2. ProductPrice.
3. ProductAmount.

And in NotArrivedOrder I have this :

1. OrderId
2. ProductName
3. ProductPrice
4. ProductAmount
5. ArriveDate

And I want to insert to products all the orders that arrived(that today date is bigger then the arrived date).

How can I do it ? (there's a copy query or something like that).

I tried this :

```
INSERT INTO Products 
values(Select ProductName,ProductPrice,ProductAmount FROM NotArrivedOrder Where ArriveDate ='30/05/2013')"
```

and I'm getting this errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keywork 'Select'
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   the conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: do you know SQL language? can you write teh SELECT query you want to use for data exctraction and the INSERT query you want to use for data insert? Once you have these two SQL statements, we can combine them together

Comment: 1 im using SQL server

2 i tryd somthing like that , didnt work.

3 the arrive date is 30/05/2013

Comment: @ShmulikCohen you dont need values keyword....try like as i suggested in my answer...

Comment: You need to **either** use `INSERT INTO Products(list of columns) VALUES(explicit values)` , or then use `INSERT INTO Products(list of columns) SELECT (list of columns) FROM ......`. You **cannot** mix the `VALUES` and `SELECT` methods. Also: I would strongly recommend to **always** define an explicit list of columns in your `INSERT INTO ....` statement - just to be safe

Answer (score 3):

Please try this..

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT 
SELECT ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductAmount 
FROM NotArrivedOrder 
WHERE ArriveDate<CONVERT(nvarchar(50),GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.......

```
 Insert Into Product(ProductName,
    ProductPrice,
    ProductAmount)  (Select ProductName,
    ProductPrice,
    ProductAmount
    from NotArrivedOrder  where Casr(ArriveDate as Datetime)< GetDate())
```

Comment: @ShmulikCohen Ccheck here it works file like this ..http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c91a0/1

Comment: @ShmulikCohen @AmitSingh That's `insert into (...) values (...)` (I think; I might be wrong).

Comment: @michaelb958 it doesn't need value key word check sql fiddle in comment it works well

Comment: In that case, SQLfiddle and the OP might be using different DBs (again, *maybe*).

Answer (score 0):

**Query:**

```
insert into Product 
values(select productname,ProductPrice,ProductAmount 
       from NotArrived order 
       where ArriveDate<GetDate())
```

**C# Code:**

```
    try
    {
    con.open();
    cmd=new sqlcommand("insert into Product values(select productname,ProductPrice,ProductAmount from NotArrived order where ArriveDate<GetDate())",conn);
    cmd.executenonquery();
    con.close();
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
     con.close();
    }
```

Comment: im tring , im getting this error  | " Incorrect syntax near the keyword Select
Incorrect Syntax Near ')'

Comment: Yes , it is . what do you think I can do ?

Comment: are you using sqlserver 2008 or 2005?

Comment: I can tell that the version is '10.00.2531' I dont know if is 2008 or 2005